# Testing eventListener in componentDidMount

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I have a `react-native` component that is listening to `Linking` url event. How would I fire that Event with `react-native-testing-library`?

Example:

```js
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Linking, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import SafariView from 'react-native-safari-view';

class WebAuthView extends Component<Props, State> {
  componentDidMount() {
        Linking.addEventListener('url', this.handleAuthUrl);
        SafariView.addEventListener('onDismiss', this.handleDismiss);
   }

   componentWillUnmount() {
       Linking.removeEventListener('url', this.handleAuthUrl);
       SafariView.removeEventListener('onDismiss', this.handleDismiss);
   }

   handleAuthUrl = ({url}) => {
     // Implementation goes here
   }

   render() {
     // ....
   }
}
```

Comment: You could mock it using basic jest functionality. I don't think that react testing library has anything for this use case

Comment: @Y.Gherbi i know that i can mock it using jest. But I want to know how to fire that event. Linking has no `emit` function

Answer (score 2):

In my attempt to solve this problem, I manually mocked the `Linking` module within the test file that was testing deep links.

```js
jest.mock('Linking', () => {
  const listeners = [];

  return {
    addEventListener: jest.fn((event, handler) => {
      listeners.push({ event, handler });
    }),

    emit: jest.fn((event, props) => {
      listeners.filter(l => l.event === event).forEach(l => l.handler(props));
    }),
  };
});
```

I then manually emitted the event for the given test.

```js
it('handles deep links to content', () => {
  render(<App />);
  Linking.emit('url', { url: 'https://test.com/content/foo' });
  expect(Link.navigateToURL).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

The negative to this approach is that if React Native modifies the API for the `Linking` module, my mock will hide any conflicts from those updates and my tests will result in false positives. However, I was unable to find a more appropriate and adaptable solution with Jest and React Native. I will just have to keep an eye on any `Linking` module updates.